# How does the compiler know what datatype the lambda expression should be

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

So when using EF Core and you use most of the Linq extensions you actually use `System.Linq.Expressions` instead of the usual `Func`.

So lets say you are using `FirstOrDefault` on a `DbSet`.

```cs
DbContext.Foos.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Bar == true);
```

When you `ctrl` + `lmb` on `FirstOrDefault` it will show you the following overload:

```cs
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
```

But there is also an overload for `Func`:

```cs
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
```

When you want to store an expression in a variable you can do something like the following:

```cs
Func<Entity, bool> = x => x.Bar == true;
```

and

```cs
Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> = x => x.Bar == true;
```

So how does the compiler decide which overload should be used while using these extension methods?

Comment: It's complicated... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/overload-resolution

Comment: In case of a func<T, TResult> as input parameter for FirstAndDefault(), the compiler can only use the IEnumerable overload because a func<> cannot be translated to SQL to be passed to the database. It might have something to do with this.

Comment: @DavidG I guess this applies for .Net in general?

Comment: @Bensjero Well this does still not make sense.

Comment: I realise I linked to the VB docs instead of C#. C# has it's own rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Inherited class proximity matters more than exact method parameter types

Notice that the `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` variant applies to `IQueryable<T>`, whereas the `Func<T, bool>` variant applies to `IEnumerable<T>`.
When looking for a matching method, the compiler will always pick the one closest to the object's type. The inheritance hierarchy is as follows:

```
DbSet<T> : IQueryable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
```

*Note: there may be other inheritances inbetween, but that doesn't matter. What matters is which is closest to `DbSet<T>`. `IQueryable<T>` is closer related to `DbSet<T>` than `IEnumerable<T>`.*

Therefore, the compiler will try to find a matching method in `IQueryable<T>`. It asks two questions:

- Does this type have a method by that name?
- Do the method parameter types match/map?

`IQueryable<T>` has a `FirstOrDefault` method, so bullet point 1 is satisfied); and since `x => x.MyBoolean` can be implicitly converted to an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, bullet point 2 is also satisfied.

Therefore, you end up with the `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` variant defined on `IQueryable<T>`.

*Suppose* `x => x.MyBoolean` could **not** be implicitly converted to `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` but could be converted to `Func<T,bool>` (note: this isn't the case, but this could happen for other types/values), then bullet point 2 would **not** have been satisfied.
At this point, since the compiler did not find a match in `IQueryable<T>`, it will keep looking further, stumbling on `IEnumerable<T>` and ask itself the same questions (bullet points). Both bullet points would have been satified.

Therefore, in this case, you would've ended up with the `Func<T,bool>` variant defined on `IEnumerable<T>`.

### Update

[Here's a dotnetfiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zrd33q).

Notice that even though I pass `int` values (which the base method signature uses), The  `double` signature of the `Derived` class fits (because `int` implicitly converts to `double`) and the compiler never looks in the `Base` class.

However, this isn't true in `Derived2`. Since `int` does not implicitly convert to `string`, there is no match found in `Derived2`, and the compiler looks further in `Base` and uses the `int` method from `Base`.

Comment: Now here's a question that might bake your brain a bit. Suppose Base has a method `public void M(Derived)` and Derived has a method `public void M(Base)`. If you call `derived.M(derived)`, which method gets called, `Base.M`, or `Derived.M`, and why? The answer might surprise you but it makes good sense.

Comment: @EricLippert Following the same logic, I'd say `Derived.M` to be called (since `Derived` implicitly converts to `Base`, similar to my `double` vs `int` example fiddle), and [that seems to hold true](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mZw19U). Based on your comment I was starting to expect it was going to be the opposite though :)

Comment: Most people forget to look at the receiver and only look at the arguments; based solely on the arguments you'd expect `Base.M(Derived)` to be called because the argument is more specific, but C# considers the specificity of the *receiver* to be more important than the specificity of the *argument* because **the implementation you are calling is inside the receiver!**

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is a reasonable explanation, but I thought I might provide a little more detail.

> So lets say you are using FirstOrDefault on a DbSet. `DbContext.Foos.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Bar == true);`

First off, I hope you would not write that. If you want to ask "is it raining?" do you ask "is it raining?" or do you ask "is the statement that it is raining a true statement?"  Just say `FirstOrDefault(x => x.Bar)`.

Next, given these overloads:

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
    Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)

public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
```

How does the compiler choose which overload is the best?

First we do *type inference* to determine what `TSource` is in each.  The details of the type inference algorithm are complex; ask a more focussed question if you have a question about it.

If type inference fails to determine a type for `TSource` in either, the failed inference method is discarded from the set of candidates. In your example `TSource` can be determined to be `Foo`, presumably.

Next, of the candidates that remain, we check them for *applicability of arguments to formals*.  That is, can we convert every supplied argument to its corresponding formal parameter type?  (And of course, is the number of arguments provided correct, and so on.)  In your example both methods are applicable.

Of the applicable candidates that remain, we now enter a round of *betterness checking*. How does betterness checking work? Again, we do it argument-by-argument. In this case we have two questions to answer:

- `DbContext.Foos` can be converted to either `IEnumerable<Foo>` or `IQueryable<Foo>`. Which, if either, is the better conversion?
- The lambda can be converted to either a delegate or an expression tree. Which, if either, is the better conversion?

The second question is easy to answer: neither is better.  We learn nothing from this argument with respect to betterness.

To answer the first question, we apply the rule *conversion to specific is better than conversion to general*.  If given a choice to convert to Giraffe or Mammal, converting to Giraffe is better. So now the question is which is *more specific*, `IQueryable<Foo>` or `IEnumerable<Foo>`?

The rule of specificity checking is straightforward: if X can be implicitly converted to Y but Y cannot be implicitly converted to X, then X is the more specific.  A Giraffe can be used where an Animal is needed, but an Animal cannot be used where a Giraffe is needed, so Giraffe is more specific.  Or: every giraffe is an animal, but not every animal is a giraffe, so giraffe is more specific.

By this measure, `IQueryable<T>` is more specific than `IEnumerable<T>` because every queryable is an enumerable but not every enumerable is a queryable.

So the queryable is more specific, and therefore that conversion is better.

Now we ask the question "is there a *unique* applicable candidate method where compared to *every* other candidate, *at least one conversion was better* and *no conversion was worse*?"  There is; the queryable candidate has the property that it is better in one argument than every other, and not worse in every other argument, and it is the unique method that has this property.

Therefore overload resolution chooses that method.

I encourage you to read the specification if you have more questions.

Comment: That is a lot of useful and interesting information, I really appreciate it. I would have never thought that there would be so much logic behind it!

Comment: @Twenty: You're welcome. We tried hard to be principled in the design of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most useful place to look in the C# spec is [Anonymous Function Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#anonymous-function-expressions):

> An anonymous function does not have a value or type in and of itself, but is convertible to a compatible delegate or expression tree type
>
> ...
>
> In an implicitly typed parameter list, the types of the parameters are inferred from the context in which the anonymous function occurs—specifically, when the anonymous function is converted to a compatible delegate type or expression tree type, that type provides the parameter types.

Which then leads us to [Anonymous Function Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#anonymous-function-conversions):

> A lambda expression `F` is compatible with an expression tree type `Expression<D>` if `F` is compatible with the delegate type `D`. Note that this does not apply to anonymous methods, only lambda expressions.

---

Those are the dry bits from the spec. However, it's also helpful to read Eric Lippert's [How do we ensure that type inference terminates](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/10/02/how-do-we-ensure-that-method-type-inference-terminates/) to pull bits together.